# How to display detailed information inside modal

Tags: website-design, info-visualisation, web, wizard

I'm currently designing a 3-step creator for detecting objects in a live video stream with the help of AI.

The modal below shows the video and the radio button-like object selectors. However, I also want the user to know the limitations of the AI (limitations in darkness, objects must be close enough, etc) in order to set the right expectations for the user.

Right now I have a collapsible section, but I feel like it's a bit shoehorned where it is now and the area is too small to display anything meaningful.

I'd like to be able to display around 100 words of content.

Any ideas of how to present this content?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other designs? If yes, can you add them to give a better view on the problem?

Comment: @RomanVidenov there is a box around the object in the video.

Comment: @jazZRo I have not. It still has to be a modal and a step-by-step guide as shown above.

Comment: @Chris ok, all clear. What if the AI detected an object on, for example, 0:02 sec and another one later 0:08 sec? Should the user pick one or two of them?

Comment: @RomanVidenov The system would only draw boxes around the object type the user selected. If the user selects only vehicles, the AI would ignore any humans detected. The user does not interact with any specific object, they just select which type they are interested in.

Comment: @Chris hmm, what is the purpose of this UI? What value does it bring?

Comment: @RomanVidenov the program will generate an event when something is detected in the video. For example, send an email when a car enters a pedestrian-only area. For surveillance purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why the information sits inside a modal?

The rule of thumb is that modal is preferable when there is a cause to disrupt the current user flow and to direct their attention on what is presented in the modal. The modal also gives the user the ability to exit the current process and go back to what they were doing before.

However, if you find that very detailed information is required to be presented to the user, and that the user shouldn't be able to exit the current process then it might not be necessary to limit yourself to showing the information inside a modal.

In the modern day of responsive and mobile first design, there really isn't too much difference between layout and design for the components that you have listed there whether it has to go into a full window or modal, except for the size consideration. However, for the sake of greater accessibility and ease of use, it is a good idea to consider if you can break it down into smaller and simpler steps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 100 words.

"Proper lighting and focus are everything.
Low quality videos will yield fewer identifiable objects."

Comment: I wish that decision was mine :)